# Overriding template not working in dev branch

Tags: magento2, layout, template-override

I have overridden a file

> vendor/magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/view/frontend/templates/customer/address/edit.phtml

and placed the replaced file in:

> app/design/frontend/ParentTheme/childTheme/Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes/templates/customer/address/edit.phtml

This overriding works fine in local, but if I deploy the same to the dev branch, it shows a completely blank page.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: have you checked logs? any error?

Comment: No, nothing in logs

Comment: Is your magento in developer mode or production mode in dev branch?

Comment: Its production mode in dev branch. Will change to dev and check once